# Docker Angular run-scripts issue

Tags: angular, docker, npm

My `Dockerfile` for Angular App

```
FROM node:10.15.3-alpine as builder

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apk add git
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm i

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm run-script build
```

It exits on last step with the following error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-05-24T09_05_54_385Z-debug.log
```

Is run-script missing or build option in this case? and how to fix or what's the alternative??

**script-section** of `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "edu-start": "ng serve --project edu-app",
    "edu-start-with-api": "ng serve --project edu-app --configuration local_api",
    "edu-start-with-nodejs": "ng serve --project edu-app --configuration local_nodejs",
    "edu-build-dev": "node --max_old_space_size=2048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --project edu-app --configuration hmr",
    "edu-build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=2048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --project edu-app --configuration production --prod",
    "air-pilot-start": "ng serve --project air-pilot-app",
    "air-pilot-build-dev": "node --max_old_space_size=2048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --project air-pilot-app --configuration hmr",
    "air-pilot-build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=2048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --project air-pilot-app --configuration production --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
```

I tried this too instead, but neither worked, complains that ng Not Found

```
RUN ng build --prod --project edu-app
```

Comment: Please post `scripts` section of your `package.json`.

Comment: make sure you are running the script on the same place as of the package.json

Comment: @PranavRamachandran ofc its set in Dockerfile: WORKDIR /usr/src/app

Comment: @Pranav ok friend, how to fix? my dev suggests to use ng tho...

Comment: run this before your ng build command, npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `build` command at scripts section, that's the reason you are getting `missing script: build`.

So add this to `package.json`:

```
    "scripts": {
       "build": "ng build --prod --project edu-app"
      }
```

As for this and `ng` not found issue you are reporting, it is normal to happen as `@angular/cli` has not been installed globally in the container. You have two options here,

- either install it globally `npm -i -g @angular/cli`
- or access it directly through its path inside `node_modules`

I recommend the first solution as it is clearer.

So after making the change in the scripts section I told you above, your `Dockerfile` should be:

```
FROM node:10.15.3-alpine as builder

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apk add git
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm i

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm -i -g @angular/cli && npm run-script build
```

Comment: I added the same line in package.json: but I get this error instead: \n
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

Comment: You have invalid syntax in `package.json`. You may use an online json validator or use an appropriate IDE which supports error highlighting. Don't forget to put a comma after each entry in scripts section(except last one) of package.json